# Can configure Jenkins pipeline with fastlane commands in xcode project file

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

i'm working on iOS project which have continous intergration set up, i wanted to create a jenkins pipeline for my project to run automation steps to do build,test and etc operations. For the automation process i'm using Fastlane tool, so how can i sync up the jenkins pipeline with my Fastlane commands in it? I got few examples related to maven commands in pipeline file, as maven plugin option is already available in jenkins, similary how can i achieve the same for fastlane. I need few examples to write my declarative pipeline syntax in my xcode project jenkins file.

Also i would like to know should the jenkinspipe line file should be inside the xcode project or it should be under the master branch ?

Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Refer Following Document for configuration of jenkins with fastlane.

https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/upload_to_app_store/#jenkins-integration